# Is multiplying by 0 faster than any other multiplication in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to optimize matrix multiplications (weighs regression) in Python by masking some values I know I don't need in computations as zeros. They will still be there as I don't want to change size of the matrices. Matrices are floats.

Will Python (keras/tensorflow?) treat these multiplications in different way and significantly speed up the process, or it will take similar amount of time, making such masking pointless?

Comment: Why don't you time both approaches and find out for yourself?

Comment: Although it's unclear what you're asking, read more about sparse tensors https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/SparseTensor

Comment: If the number of zeros is significant, you can use sparse tensors.

Comment: Thanks - I have checked it and sparse tensors are the exactly the solution I was looking for. Shortcut for people interested in it in the future:
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-04316-3
https://github.com/AlliedToasters/synapses

Answer (score 1):

No, the multiplying by zero is the same as multiplying by any other number

```
>>> def times_zero(x):
...     return x * 0
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(times_zero)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> def times_four(x):
...     return x * 4
... 
>>> dis.dis(times_four)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (4)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I timed them:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import itertools

my_toggle = itertools.cycle(range(2))

for x in range(20):
    current_number = my_toggle.__next__()
    start = timer()
    y = 1 * current_number
    end = timer()
    print(f"{end - start:.10f} seconds for {current_number}")
```

But I'm not sure what to make of the results:

```
0.0000002555 seconds for 0
0.0000002555 seconds for 1
0.0000002555 seconds for 0
0.0000002555 seconds for 1
0.0000002555 seconds for 0
0.0000000000 seconds for 1
0.0000000000 seconds for 0
0.0000002555 seconds for 1
0.0000000000 seconds for 0
0.0000000000 seconds for 1
0.0000000000 seconds for 0
0.0000002555 seconds for 1
0.0000002555 seconds for 0
0.0000000000 seconds for 1
0.0000002555 seconds for 0
0.0000000000 seconds for 1
0.0000000000 seconds for 0
0.0000002555 seconds for 1
0.0000000000 seconds for 0
0.0000000000 seconds for 1
```

Comment: Nothing surprising here. You made **one** timing in which your CPU may have been busy doing other stuff. Try this in more empiric approach, such as `timeit.Timer.repeat` with very large numbers for `repeat` and `number`

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks for the tip. Haven't really touched timing of this type of stuff yet. I'm going to look into it.